# tkinter image bad quality

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm coding an Password Manager for myself and I want to use pictures in the interface (tkinter). The problem there is, that these images have a pretty bad resolution when I resize them to a smaller resolution.

It looks like this:

[image]

I want them to look better than this picture above

Comment: if it's for yourself it shouldn't matter too much. Shrinking any image will result in a loss of detail. Other options are to find a smaller starting image or a vector image(svg) that you can save at a smaller resolution

Comment: You may be able to get higher quality images by using the `pillow` modules [`ImageTk.Photoimage`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageTk.html?highlight=ImageTk#PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage) class. These support more image types that `tkinter` does, as well as additional methods. Plus it supports several different image resizing filters, notable one for anti-aliasing the results when resampling an image when its size is changed. See [**Image resizing filters**](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes/2.7.0.html#image-resizing-filters).

Comment: Maybe the images are not made to be resized; they might have a fixed resolution.